# How to create a Label widget with a transparent background using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to create an app which has an image as its background. But when I add a `Label` over the image, the label had a white background.

Is there a way to set the `Label` widget's background color to 'transparent'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to make Label backgrounds transparent.  One alternative is to use a Canvas widget as the base for the whole thing, then use the `create_image` method to add the background image, and `create_text` to make the text labels.  It will be a bit more work, but the text should render without a background on top of the image.  (Admittedly I have very little experience with the Canvas widget, so I'm speaking more from theory than experience, but it's worth a try.)

If you don't have a good Tkinter reference, I highly recommend [this one made by New Mexico Tech](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html).  It's available as a [downloadable PDF](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf) as well.

Comment: Thanks Justin. It worked perfectly for me. But now I have another query over this. 
Can we add other widgets (label, OptionMenu, Entry) over Canvas ?
As far I searched, I could see that we are able to add arc, bitmap kind of things.

Comment: That Tkinter reference that I mentioned in my answer tells how you can add other widgets to a Canvas using the canvas's `create_window` method.  You can use this to place individual widgets, or use it to place a Frame containing a collection of widgets.