# How to display text on screen with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this question already exists in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840133/how-to-display-text-on-the-screen-without-a-window-using-python). But I am going for a slightly different requirement. This text displays on top of every window but instead want it to only display on the desktop(The screen you get as soon as you enter the pin to your laptop. In case my vocabulary was bad). But not on top of any other windows. Here is the code.

It is the exact same as the question I linked above but still:

```
label = tkinter.Label(text='Text on the screen', font=('Times','50'), fg='black', bg='white')
label.master.overrideredirect(True)
label.master.geometry("+550+250")
label.master.lift()
label.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
label.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
label.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
label.pack()
label.mainloop()
```

I have searched the internet coud not seem to find a solution pls help.

Answer (score 0):

> This text displays on top of every window but instead want it to only
> display on the desktop(The screen you get as soon as you enter the pin
> to your laptop.

The link that was posted doesn't work isn't on this present.

The widget doesn't do on `label.mainloop()`. That was an old version.

Easier way write a short script.

Add this `padx=25, pady=25` for `Label` widget or suit your need.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

ws = tk.Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.overrideredirect(True)
ws.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','white')
ws.config(bg="white")
#ws.config(bg='#D9D8D7')
ws.geometry('700x300')

label = tk.Label(text='Text on the screen',
                 font=('Times','50'),
                 fg='black',
                 bg='white',
                 width=50)

 
label.pack(padx=25, pady=25)

ws.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Well after 1 tab change it basically is gone but this is an improvement