# How to display text with a background without a window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

My program generates a list of tuples every second, the tuple has text and its coordinates. I need to display the text on a rectangle (background), within the framework of which everything will be transparent, without program windows, and after a second redraw everything. Also, what is drawn should be ignored by the mouse.Thanks.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105730/23301946 close and changed the code a bit:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32ui

import multiprocessing
import time
import random

def generate_random_coordinates():
    x = random.randint(0, 1920)
    y = random.randint(0, 1080)
    return x, y

def generate_random_text():
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
    text = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 8)))
    return text

def main():
    hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle()
    className = 'MyWindowClassName'

    wndClass = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
    wndClass.style = win32con.CS_HREDRAW | win32con.CS_VREDRAW
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = wndProc
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance
    wndClass.hCursor = win32gui.LoadCursor(None, win32con.IDC_ARROW)
    wndClass.hbrBackground = win32gui.GetStockObject(win32con.WHITE_BRUSH)
    wndClass.lpszClassName = className
    wndClassAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wndClass)

    exStyle = (
        win32con.WS_EX_COMPOSITED |
        win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED |
        win32con.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE |
        win32con.WS_EX_TOPMOST |
        win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    )
    
    style = win32con.WS_DISABLED | win32con.WS_POPUP | win32con.WS_VISIBLE

    hWindow = win32gui.CreateWindowEx(
        exStyle,
        wndClassAtom,
        None,
        style,
        0,
        0,
        win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSCREEN),
        win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSCREEN),
        None,
        None,
        hInstance,
        None
    )

    win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWindow, 0x00ffffff, 255, win32con.LWA_COLORKEY | win32con.LWA_ALPHA)

    win32gui.SetWindowPos(hWindow, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        win32con.SWP_NOACTIVATE | win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE | win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW)

    win32gui.PumpMessages()

def wndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam):
    if message == win32con.WM_PAINT:
        x, y = generate_random_coordinates()
        text = generate_random_text()

        hdc, paintStruct = win32gui.BeginPaint(hWnd)

        dpiScale = win32ui.GetDeviceCaps(hdc, win32con.LOGPIXELSX) / 60.0
        fontSize = 24

        lf = win32gui.LOGFONT()
        lf.lfFaceName = "Times New Roman"
        lf.lfHeight = int(round(dpiScale * fontSize))
        lf.lfQuality = win32con.NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY
        hf = win32gui.CreateFontIndirect(lf)
        win32gui.SelectObject(hdc, hf)

        text_position = (x, y)

        # Get the size of the text
        text_size = win32gui.GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, text)

        # Set up the rectangle around the text
        text_rect = (
            text_position[0] - 5,
            text_position[1] - 5,
            text_position[0] + text_size[0] + 5,
            text_position[1] + text_size[1] + 5
        )

        # Create a blue brush for the text background
        gray_brush = win32gui.CreateSolidBrush(win32api.RGB(50, 50, 50))
        win32gui.FillRect(hdc, text_rect, gray_brush)

        # Draw the text with transparency
        win32gui.SetTextColor(hdc, win32api.RGB(220, 220, 220))
        win32gui.DrawText(
            hdc,
            text,
            -1,
            text_rect,
            win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_NOCLIP | win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_VCENTER
        )

        # Release resources
        win32gui.DeleteObject(gray_brush)
        win32gui.EndPaint(hWnd, paintStruct)
        return 0

    elif message == win32con.WM_DESTROY:
        print('Closing the window.')
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0)
        return 0

    else:
        return win32gui.DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, name="Main", args=())
    p.start()

    time.sleep(5)

    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

But there are problems with the background, also I don't know how to dynamically update the information in this case. Perhaps there are more modern methods.

Comment: You could use tkinter and then make the window be transparent and not have a border

Comment: I tested it on tkinter and almost everything worked but I couldn't get the text with the background to ignore the mouse clicks. By clicking on the text, I have to interact with objects in the background. That's why I switched to pywin32.

Answer (score 0):

When programming, you can't just make stuff appear on the screen. Modern computers have a module called the "Windows Manager" that decides what goes where on the screen, what is on top, etc, etc. These modules are very complex and use highly advanced methods to communicate with programs.

When creating a program that wants to use the screen, you should use a library to talk to the Windows Manager for you. These libraries know how to talk to the Windows Manager.

Python has one library built-in that is guaranteed to work on the computer you are using: `tkinter`. It is based on an old bit of GUI code called `tcl/tk`. That is why GUI's generated with it look a bit weird, but in many cases it will be good enough, probably including yours. If not, other options include making a dynamic web-page that you can open in a browser, the `pyqt` or `pyside` libraries (they are very similar), `kivy` for applications on a mobile platform, or `wxpython`. These have a steeper learning curve than `tkinter`, though. Using the raw `win32` calls is the next level of complexity, with the added problem that it teaches you bad coding practices. These calls are decidedly un-pythonic.

I would advice you to walk through a `tkinter` tutorial.