How do I undo the drawing made by GDI+ directly on the screen?
I'm working on an overlay-type program in C++, that requires me to draw directly on the screen.
I've used GDI+ so far, and it has worked pretty well. I want however to undo all the drawing before the user exits the program.
I also want this process to be relatively fast, avoiding things like opening a window and closing it fast to get rid of the drawings.
...
HDC window = GetDC(0);
Graphics graphics(window);
Pen gp(Color::DarkOliveGreen, 3);
SolidBrush gpb(Color::DarkOliveGreen);
SolidBrush cp(Color(0,0,0,0));
SolidBrush bp(Color(255, 0, 0, 0));
graphics.FillEllipse(&gpb, matpos[0][0] - 5, matpos[0][1] - 5, 10, 10);
graphics.FillEllipse(&gpb, matpos[1][0] - 5, matpos[1][1] - 5, 10, 10);
graphics.DrawRectangle(&gp, get_rect_from_points(Rect(matpos[0][0], matpos[0][1], matpos[1][0], matpos[1][1])));
...

How do I approach this?
I tried to draw a transparent element over my previous drawings, hoping that it would update them and get rid of the drawings, but that did not work. I also tried the RedrawWindow win32 function, but without any success.

Maybe related Drawing overlays with GDI+

Why don't you draw on an overlay window rather than on the screen?

You cannot undo drawing operations. They are destructive. The system doesn't remember a previous state. Luckily, you don't have to anyway. Since rendering into a foreign DC is unreliable you'll have to go with a different approach altogether. The standard solution is to create your own (transparent) window to render into.

Update: found a work around with InvalidateRect. Seems to work at a first glance, will require further testing though

"Seems to work at a first glance" - Right. And by that, you also found a convenient way to prove the point I made earlier: "Rendering into a foreign DC is unreliable". Since anyone (including the legal owner of the window) can call InvalidateRect() at any time, the assumption that whatever you rendered into this foreign DC would remain there until you decide for it to change has lost its rational foundation.

I was aware a proper implementation would be to have an invisible window fullscreened at all times and for it to always sit on the bottom. But I had performance concerns. I am working on a tool that is active permanently where you can select a rectangle on the screen and use ocr to get the text from it then copy it into the clipboard. I will try to implement this properly and see how it works

If you are fine with per-window granularity you can use the GraphicsCapturePicker instead of rolling your own. And rolling your own is far more intricate to implement than you would assume. Indeed, I only know of one solution that a) requires a custom window, and b) cannot be active at all times.

So I did some more testing. InvalidateRect and UpdateWindow() resolve my issue and they do it fast, I dont need to clear the screen only once, so its good enoufh, and it worked on 2 of my machines.

Ill still look into what you mentioned though

You're wasting your time if you keep following down that path. You will eventually have to create a window anyway to handle mouse input (and prevent mouse input from reaching the window underneath). The only type of window that is visually transparent but still receives mouse input requires DirectX rendering. Those are the really hard problems you need to solve first, because if you cannot then all your rendering experiments are moot.

@How2Code  IInspectable is right. You can not receive mouse input when window is transparent just by gdi+. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78312713/which-windows-api-can-be-used-to-make-transparent-text-on-top-of-the-screen/78314642#78314642 When window is transparent, the click and mouse events will go to the window underneath.
