# How to make labels background to be transparent in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to create a GUI in python.

What I did was I insert a GIF image into the background and also created labels and buttons.

How do I make the labels and buttons background to be transparent as the background is covering my GIF image?

Comment: Can't you just create some transparent GIFs and use them as the images for your `Label` and `Button` widgets?

Comment: Show us the code!! Also does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039481/how-to-create-transparent-widgets-using-tkinter) help?

Comment: I think there is no transparency in Tk.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what @Paul Rooney indicated in his comment above.

You might be able to workaround this using canvas to create your own label. You can then use a canvas text object instead of a label.

If you create an empty canvas and add the text with the create_text(), and then place this text-canvas 'on top' of the 'main' canvas, it should simulate what you want. The reason for using two canvases is to prevent scrollability.

I can not think of way to this for buttons though..

Please post your code if you need an example of this :)