# Is there a way to make just the label background invisible/transparent using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, invisible

I wrote a simple GUI program using Tkinter (ttk):

In the center of the window, there's a label with an image.
The image self is a transparent GIF. But if the image has alpha-background, you can see through the image and see the background color of the label.

[image: View example]

**Is there an way to make JUST the image on the label visible and not the label(-background) itself?**

If I try it with common ways, the whole label disappears. And I won't set the background color to `'White'`, because I need this method in other cases when the background is coloured in more than one colour.

//Edit: This doesen't work:

```
labelSpeichern=ttk.Label(root, image=predef.speicherngif, background="Transparent")
labelSpeichern.place(x= 250, y=300, width= 200, height=40)
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of your code which highlights the problem?

Comment: @Luke.py I edited my Question and posted some code not works.

Comment: Have you tried using a tk.Label rather than a ttk.Label?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is: The colour `transpaerent` doesen't exist. What can I do else?

Comment: Try this?- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039481/how-to-create-transparent-widgets-using-tkinter

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039481/how-to-create-transparent-widgets-using-tkinter) can help you. Can you show any more of the code?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to make that but I will lern it :)

Comment: all Tkinter widget have non-transparent background and you can't change it. You have to use `tk.Canvas` and draw all elements on canvas.

Comment: @j_4321 Sorry, but I used 'advanced search' and it found nothing useful.