# How to make a GIF move across the window and respond to a click

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, I need to have a GIF image move across a window every 2 seconds, and when it's clicked on to have a splash screen show. I have absolutely no idea how to import an image and have it move / respond to a click, and I can't find a straight answer elsewhere.

Thanks

Comment: You can be more precise with your question and also write a bit about what your tried and what you got stuck on. Due to your general question you got a few down-votes. If my answer helps you, you can upvote it and and accept it as the right answer. If you it doesn't you can leave a comment and I might check back (or someone else might see it).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example, some notes:

1. tkinter doesn't animate gifs, you can do it manually if you want ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518072/play-animations-in-gif-with-tkinter))
2. This is Python3 code, in Python2 some things are different (import names, calling super, etc).
3. The label has a background even if the image is transparent, there are workarounds ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814937/tkinter-transparency-on-label))
4. In this example we take an image (named s.gif and placed next to the code file) and place it at (0,0) then every 2seconds it moves by 10 in both x and y (mod size of frame). when it gets clicked we show a splash frame for a second and then remove it (since that's the point of "splash")

---

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Toplevel
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label


class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()
        self._root = root

        # Init class variables
        self._size = 300
        self._image_label = None
        self.image_place = 0

        self.init_ui()

        # Acutally run the UI
        root.mainloop()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Init general layour
        self._root.geometry("{size}x{size}+{size}+{size}".format(size=self._size))
        self.master.title("Absolute positioning")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)  # show this frame

        # Setup image
        path_to_iamge = "s.gif"
        s_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path_to_iamge).convert("RGBA")) # Convert to RGBA to get transparency
        # place image in a label, we are going to be moving this frame around
        self._image_label = Label(self, image=s_image)
        self._image_label.image = s_image
        # Make image clickable, running show_splash when clicked
        self._image_label.bind("<Button-1>", self._show_splash)

        self._place_image_label()

    def _place_image_label(self):
        # Show image label
        self._image_label.place(x=self.image_place, y=self.image_place)
        # increase image coordination for next time
        self.image_place = (self.image_place + 10) % self._size
        # reschedule to run again in 2 seconds
        self._root.after(2000, self._place_image_label)

    def _show_splash(self, event):
        splash = Toplevel(self)
        # update UI with splash
        self.update()
        # schedule to close splash after a 1 second
        self._root.after(1000, lambda: splash.destroy())


def main():
    Example(Tk())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```